# Any way to limit the amount of memory a program leaks?

Tags: memory, netbeans

I'm running Netbeans on Windows Vista and I have to restart the computer every 6 hours because while Netbeans is running I seem to be constantly leaking memory. This doesn't happen while I'm running any other program.

Would it possible to run Netbeans inside some kind of sandbox to limit how much it can leak memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netbeans is a Java application, you can limit how much the JRE uses in **Control Panel -> Java**.

Under the **Java** tab, enter `-XmxNM` as your runtime settings for your current JRE, where `N` is the amount of memory in MB you want available to the JVM.

example:

[image]

Comment: How to access the control panel under linux?

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to explore the memory leak problem, see [DevFaqMemoryLeaks](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqMemoryLeaks).

If this is a bug in Netbeans (I assume you're using the its latest version and the same for Java), you might present this info on the Netbeans forums.